# Is it possible to scale pinned datatips?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]
Here you can see that the datatips' size incomparable, I need to put my eyes on the monitor to see that font.

Yes, I can Ctrl+Scroll, but in this case I'll see only 20-30 lines of code.
So please help me to scale this datatips without scaling code.